# Problemas WebService ASMX

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asmx

Quando envio um retorno JSON e o texto tem acentuação, o JSON quebra.

---

> Aqui está o código da requisição no Controller

```
$http.post("../backend/controller/SugestaoController.asmx/comboListarSugestoes", { empresa: $rootScope.login })
    .then(function (retorno) {
        //console.log("teste", retorno.data);
        $scope.listaSugestoes = retorno.data;
    }).catch(function (retorno) {
        alert("erro");
    })
    .finally(function () {
        $scope.mostrarLoader = false;
    });
```

> Agora o lado Servidor, vou mostrar apenas como está o envio:

```
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String json = js.Serialize(retorno);
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Charset  = "utf-8";
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            //context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (json.Length).ToString());
            context.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            context.Response.Write(json);
```

> Se tiver acentos, o JSON chega assim:

```
[{nome:'felipe',funcao:'médico',idade:23
```

> Se não tiver, ele chega normal

```
[{nome:'felipe',funcao:'medico',idade:23}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei dizer com certeza, mas um palpite: ao informar o tamanho da resposta no Content-Length, use o tamanho em bytes, não a quantidade de caracteres da string. Isso pode ocorrer, pois os caracteres acentuados adicionam alguns bytes na string. Então ao invés de fazer:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (json.Length).ToString());
```

Você faz:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json).Length.ToString());
```

Comment: Vou tentar Júlio, obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Júlio, muito obrigado.